# Printing a boolean boolean value between classes

Tags: java, class, object, boolean, boolean-operations

I'm relatively new to Java. I got an assignment where I have to output a object of a class showing its properties and also turn it on.The object is a 'fan' and I can print all its properties from the FAB class that I have created except turning it on.
here is a bit of my code

```
public class Fan {
private boolean on = false;

public Fan ( int newSpeed, boolean newOn, double newRadius, String newColor ) {

            setSpeed(newSpeed);    
            setRadius(newRadius);
            setColor(newColor);
            }

            public boolean isOn () { 
            return true;

            }
           public void setOn ( boolean newOn ) {
                    if (on) {
                        on=newOn;


                    } 
                    }
         public String toString ( ) {                
            {
               if (on)
               {
                  return "Fan is Turned on";
               }
               else
               {
                  return "Fan is Turned off";
               }
                  }
                    }
```

and this is my object for fan class

```
public class TestApplication {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Fan testfan1 = new Fan(5, false, 10, "blue");

    System.out.println(testfan1.getSpeed() + "   " + testfan1.getColor() + " " 
            + testfan1.getRadius() + " " + testfan1.isOn());


 }
}
```

Tried so many ways, but I get the output 'true' not fan is turned on

Comment: You also never set an `on` to the value that comes from your constructor, it just stays at the default `false`

Comment: I did, but still getting false/true output. not my desired print statement as Fan is turned on

Comment: if you want a `String` as output then `isOn()` needs to return a `String` not a `boolean`

Answer (score 5):

A few things wrong that I see:

You are using the `=` operator to compare in your `if` statements.  The `=` operator is the assignment operator in Java.  Use `==` to compare.

```
if (on == true)
```

And if what you are comparing is a boolean (which is the case here), just supply the boolean only:

```
if (on)
```

Also, in your `isOn` method, you are always returning `true`, I think you meant to return `on`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks but still not getting "Fan is turned on". Here is my code                                       **                public  boolean  isOn () { 
                 return on;
                    
                }
                public void setOn ( boolean newOn ) {
                        if (on) {
                            on = newOn;
                            System.out.println("Fan is Turned on");

                        } 
                        }

Answer (score 4):

`if (on = true) {`

I think you mean

`if (on == true) {`

Which simplifies to

`if (on) {`

Captcha: Languages where = is used as assignment instead of :=, despite looking like ==, and it is not a warning to use = in an if body

EDIT: Also:

```
        public boolean isOn () { 
        return true;

        }
```

Why not `return on`?

Also:

If you print 'fan is turned on' 'fan is turned off' etc when you set the variable, it's not going to happen when you 1) get the variable via isOn 2) are concatenating a string for sending to println.

edit

```
public string ToString()
{
   if (on)
   {
      return "Fan is Turned on";
   }
   else
   {
      return "Fan is Turned off";
   }
}

System.out.println(testfan1);
```

Comment: actually it should just be `if(on){ ... }` no need to test if it `==` true or false, because being a boolean it is already true or false.

Comment: So I can't get a print output? all I am getting is false now. Not the print statement. :(

Comment: @Adnan Make a method that returns the string that you want to print. Don't print from within an instance method.

Comment: Okay suppose this is the code                                    `private String text = "Fan is turned on";` how do I link it with `boolean on = false`? This is my first time dealing with classes in Java, so please help

Comment: Thanks and I Did that, see the main code, Done exactly what u did and still getting 'false' as output! :( the toString needs to be in the main Fan class right? and also you didn't tell me what to do with Set on?

Comment: @Adnan "toString needs to be in the main Fan class right?" Yes

Comment: @Patashu : Please tell me what to do with 'Set on', what should I set there?